# save all the data of a recyclerview made of edittexts, with a single button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview made up of edittexts to input data. With each edit text I also have a "save" button so that when it is pressed the value of the corresponding edittext is saved in an arraylist. Then I read this arraylist (which is defined inside an adapter) from the mainactivity using the adapter's getInput() method, which returns the array with the edittext data. But the problem is that I need a button for each edittext in the recycler, and I wanted to do it all together with a single button. And I can't find a way since in the adapter you can't put an independent button but you have to put a button for each item. This is the code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList();
    public RecyclerView recycler;
    public Button boton;
    public ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton= findViewById(R.id.boton);
        recycler= findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
        {
            als.add("Hola");

        }
        adapter a= new adapter(als);
        recycler.setAdapter(a);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                input=a.getInput();
                for(String s: input)
                {
                    Log.i("hola",s);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mostrar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter:

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder>{

    public ArrayList<String> listDatos;
    public static ArrayList<String> input;

    public adapter(ArrayList<String> listDatos) {
        this.listDatos = listDatos;
        this.input= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist,null,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nombre.setText(listDatos.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDatos.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getInput()
    {
        return input;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText nombre;
        Button guardar;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            guardar= itemView.findViewById(R.id.guardar);
            guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    input.add(nombre.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

itemlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/guardar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guardar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Bien class:

```
public class Bien {
    private String nombre;
    private double valor;

    public Bien(String nombre, double valor) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You want to remove the buttons from each row of the RecyclerView and replace that action with just using the single top-level button? Does every row always have text entered, or would you want the saved list to omit rows where nothing was entered?

Comment: yes it's what you explain in your first question. I wan to replace all the buttons of each row, by a single top-level button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you describe, I would recommend you just add a text change listener to the EditText in each row so any time the text is updated, the stored array is also updated immediately. This way you don't need any save buttons at all, nor do you need a separate array.

That would look something like this:

```java
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder>{

    // Only need one array, it is updated as values are edited
    private ArrayList<String> listDatos;

    public adapter(ArrayList<String> listDatos) {
        this.listDatos = listDatos;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist,null,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        // add a watcher so any time the value in "nombre" is changed,
        // it updates the value stored in the array at the current
        // row's position immediately
        holder.nombre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            listDatos.set(getAdapterPosition(), s.toString());
          }
        });

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nombre.setText(listDatos.get(position));
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDatos.size();
    }

    // getInput can just return that stored array to get the
    // current state at any point (no save buttons needed)
    public ArrayList<String> getInput() {
        return listDatos;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText nombre;
        
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but that way it will be saved in the array every time I press a key. That is, if I type "hello", I will have in the arraylist: h,he,hel,hell,hello

Comment: No, if you type "hello" in row 0 you will have an array of ["hello","","",""]. As you type it may be just ["hel","","","",""] but that won't be used for anything until you initiate some other action.

Comment: The state of the list doesn't matter until they press `boton`, at which point it could save the state of the list

Comment: ah ok, but it only prints 4 elements and the arraylist should contain 7 elements. And also, i have to define as `static` the `listDatos` arraylist

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to set it so that the array does not have to be static. In general, making things static like that should be avoided where possible. I have no idea how you are seeing only 4 elements though - the list size is never changed in the code I posted.

Comment: ok, it works fine. I will figure out why only prints 4 elements. Thank you.